# How to combine spring XD with another framework?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-xd

I am trying to write a spring xd module utilizing another, proprietary Java framework. Both spring xd and this proprietary framework demand I inherit their parent POM, which is obviously not possible.

My idea of a workaround is to find out what the Spring XD parent pom does and put that more or less into another pom in my hierarchy. How do I get this XD parent pom? Or are there better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that there is no support for "multiple inheritance" in a Maven POM.  You also don't have control of the code for either Spring XD or the other proprietary framework, so you can't change one pom.xml to inherit from the other.

One potential workaround is to structure your project as a multi-module project, where one module inherits from Spring XD's POM and another module inherits from the other framework's POM.  You might then have a third module that has dependencies on the first two, which ties the whole project together into a single deliverable.

```
MyProject
|-- MySpringXDIntegration
|   `-- pom.xml inherits from Spring XD
|-- MyProprietaryFrameworkIntegration
|   `-- pom.xml inherits from proprietary framework
`-- MyApplication
    `-- pom.xml inherits from neither Spring XD nor proprietary framework
        depends on MySpringXDIntegration
        depends on MyProprietaryFrameworkIntegration
```

If this kind of project structure isn't sufficient for some other reason, then another workaround is "inlining" the relevant portions of one of the two parent POMs.  The Spring XD parent pom.xml is visible [here](http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/xd/spring-xd-module-parent/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-xd-module-parent-1.2.1.RELEASE.pom).  For the proprietary framework, if the source code has been given to you, then you can look there.  If not, then you can simply unpack that framework's jar using `jar xf` and look for the pom.xml bundled inside.  I recommend identifying which of the 2 pom.xml files is larger.  Inherit from the larger one, and then inline the relevant bits of the smaller by copy-pasting portions of it into your own pom.xml.

One way to get a good view of exactly what a parent POM does is to create a dummy project that inherits from it, and then run `mvn help:effective-pom`.  This is especially useful if the parent POM already has a deep inheritance chain of its own.

Comment: I like the multi module approach. That seems to me the cleanest way to do things. Hopefully I'll be able to build an uberjar that way that includes all the needed dependencies so I can deploy the module!

Comment: FYI, I just needed two modules. One that inherits from my proprietary framework, one that inherits from Spring XD and depends on the other module, plus uses Spring boot to build the uberjar. The third, enclosing project is just a reactor that references those two modules.